# Embedding device in File Explorer?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, explorer, hid

You can embed a device into the File Explorer, but I'm not sure how. For example, I've downloaded the drivers for a device called SoundBot, which embeds a Bluetooth device interface into Windows Explorer. The device model I am using is the SoundBot USB Bluetooth Adapter: CSR8510 A10.

[image: Bluetooth]

How is this possible, or where should I look to start figuring this out?

Comment: That's a shell extension, not an "embedded device"

Comment: This is a Namespace shell extension (NSE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a shell extension, and that's not a simple topic. "Shell" in this context means Explorer.EXE, a core Windows executable which is responsible for not just this File Explorer but also quite a few other bits of UI such as the Start Menu. Since it's not your executable, you have to use COM to communicate with Explorer.EXE if you want to show your own custom content. Exactly which interfaces you need varies with the object you're trying to introduce.